ipywidgets buttons not responding
I'm trying to create an interactive expense management system in Jupyter Notebook using ipywidgets for the interface and pandas for data manipulation. I have set up the interface with buttons for adding, removing, and displaying expenses. However, when I click the "Add Expense" button, nothing happens. The expense is not added to the dataset, and there are no error messages. Same with other buttons.
import pandas as pd
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

file_path = 'витрати_10000.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(file_path)

print(data.head())

class ExpenseManager:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def add_expense(self, date, category, amount):
        new_expense = pd.DataFrame({"Date": [date], "Category": [category], "Amount": [amount]})
        self.data = pd.concat([self.data, new_expense], ignore_index=True)

    def remove_expense(self, index):
        if index in self.data.index:
            self.data = self.data.drop(index)
        else:
            print("Expense not found.")

    def analyze_expenses(self, period='Month'):
        if period == 'Day':
            return self.data.groupby(self.data['Date']).sum()
        elif period == 'Week':
            self.data['Week'] = pd.to_datetime(self.data['Date']).dt.isocalendar().week
            return self.data.groupby('Week').sum()
        elif period == 'Month':
            self.data['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(self.data['Date']).dt.to_period('M')
            return self.data.groupby('Month').sum()
        else:
            print("Invalid period.")

em = ExpenseManager(data)

date_input = widgets.DatePicker(description='Date:')
category_input = widgets.Text(description='Category:')
amount_input = widgets.FloatText(description='Amount:')
add_button = widgets.Button(description='Add Expense')
remove_index_input = widgets.IntText(description='Index:')
remove_button = widgets.Button(description='Remove Expense')
display_button = widgets.Button(description='Display Data')

def add_expense(b):
    em.add_expense(date_input.value, category_input.value, amount_input.value)
    print(f"Added expense: {date_input.value}, {category_input.value}, {amount_input.value}")

def remove_expense(b):
    em.remove_expense(remove_index_input.value)
    print(f"Removed expense at index: {remove_index_input.value}")

def display_data(b):
    display(em.data)

add_button.on_click(add_expense)
remove_button.on_click(remove_expense)
display_button.on_click(display_data)

display(date_input, category_input, amount_input, add_button, remove_index_input, remove_button, display_button)

period_input = widgets.Dropdown(options=['Day', 'Week', 'Month'], description='Period:')
analyze_button = widgets.Button(description='Analyze Expenses')

def analyze_expenses(b):
    period = period_input.value
    analysis = em.analyze_expenses(period)
    display(analysis)
    analysis.plot(kind='bar')
    plt.show()

analyze_button.on_click(analyze_expenses)

display(period_input, analyze_button)

def generate_pdf_report(data, filename='expense_report.pdf'):
    c = canvas.Canvas(filename, pagesize=letter)
    width, height = letter
    c.drawString(30, height - 40, "Expense Report")
    
    y = height - 80
    for i, row in data.iterrows():
        c.drawString(30, y, f"{row['Date']} - {row['Category']} - ${row['Amount']}")
        y -= 20
        if y < 40:
            c.showPage()
            y = height - 40
    
    c.save()

pdf_button = widgets.Button(description='Generate PDF Report')

def create_pdf_report(b):
    generate_pdf_report(em.data)
    print("PDF report generated.")

pdf_button.on_click(create_pdf_report)

display(pdf_button)```


I tried to add ```print()``` to handle the function call, but I guess that they are not even calling. 


Please read the section 'Help others reproduce the problem' in How do I ask a good question?, and here and in the future endeavor to adhere to that. Specifically, in this case this is not a minimal reproducible example because you don't include any of the CSV file you are using as data. Ideally, you'd include the headers and like at least two lines of toy data so we can actually run your code to sort out the issue. It would also be helpful if you specified your Jupyter tech flavor and version information.

Some of the ideas here might help you understand how to share your data.

Okay, so to 'test' it, I ended up commenting out the line data = pd.read_csv(file_path) and used data =  to the dataframe in the question post provided here. While there are definite issues, which I'll get to soon, everything seems to work for me in some way in that that buttons are responding. I bring this up because I think your title is wrong given this. Expense report throws an out of bounds error but it makes plots. And a pdf gets generated. However, I suspect I know what you are getting at. However, because of your lack of details ...

 on your system and software and indication you examined what you say you did, e.g., how did you check whether the expense was added, I am left to speculate what you are seeing and what you mean. Things work to some degree. The adding an expense triggers the Added expense:  print and running print(em.data) data before and after, I can see the expense added to the last position of the dataframe. And so I'm not sure what you mean that it didn't work? Now, I do suspect you are having trouble seeing that some things are working because I suspect you are using current Jupyter tech...

 but using outdated coding approaches when working with ipywidgets. However, the Jupyter tech you are using isn't the nice one you should be using for developing with ipywidgets currently. Again, this is all speculation since you didn't provide details about Jupyter. I will share where & how you can see your code working fairly well with my 'test' data approach. Go here and click on the top badge that says 'launch binder', or just click here to launch. Okay, once...

 the session comes up, copy and paste %pip install reportlab into a new notebook cell and run it. Next open a new notebook (or restart the kernel of the present one) and copy-paste in the code in your post. Then edit it in the way I describe in my comment that starts, "Okay, so to 'test' it...". Now run the code. Add a date, category, and amount, and press the 'Add Expense' button. You'll see JupyterLab's 'log' panel toggle along the bottom left side-ish area of the bottom status bar highlight blue to indicate activity in it. Click on the now blue 'log' panel toggle to ...

 open it. You'll see something like an orange block with the time you did that and to the right something like Added expense: 2024-05-18, ffff, 44.0. This is where your print statement went because you aren't using methods that current ipywidgets and Jupyter tech need for it to display in the notebook. In fact, I think that is the crux of your entire issue. Your think your buttons  aren't working because you are using current Jupyter Notebook with outdated approaches and aren't seeing the print() results. I speculate you weren't using JupyterLab to develop your code and ...

 so you weren't seeing the log console indicator light up. My understanding is that at this time the log console is a feature of JupyterLab that Jupyter Notebook 7 doesn't currently have. I should point out though that if you use proper methods with modern ipywidgets, nothing should be going to the log, and so while it makes it nicer to have the log console when prototyping, testing, developing and/or learning, you don't absolutely need it to work with ipywidgets at this time. Code that should work in current Jupyter Nb is achievable with some adjustments & I'll focus on that next.

Concerning code that will work with both and handles print or the equivalent of print in ways compatible with current ipywidgets, see here and my comments here.

I suspect you are thinking things aren't working when they are. (Hence, no errors.) However, in modern ipywidgets and Jupyter you have to be explicit in how you connect up the output being generated to the output area of the cell.
I suggest this version (made into an minimal reproducible example with the addition of made-up data from elsewhere) of your code as something closer to what you expect:
import pandas as pd
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display, HTML
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

file_path = 'test.csv'
#data = pd.read_csv(file_path)
data = pd.DataFrame(
    [['Captain', 'Crunch', 72],
     ['Trix', 'Rabbit', 36],
     ['Count', 'Chocula', 41],
     ['Tony', 'Tiger',  54],
     ['Buzz', 'Bee', 28],
     ['Toucan', 'Sam', 38]],
    columns=['first_name', 'last_name', 'age'])

print(data.head())

feedback_output = widgets.Output()
display(feedback_output)

class ExpenseManager:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def add_expense(self, date, category, amount):
        new_expense = pd.DataFrame({"Date": [date], "Category": [category], "Amount": [amount]})
        self.data = pd.concat([self.data, new_expense], ignore_index=True)

    def remove_expense(self, index):
        if index in self.data.index:
            self.data = self.data.drop(index)
        else:
            print("Expense not found.")

    def analyze_expenses(self, period='Month'):
        if period == 'Day':
            return self.data.groupby(self.data['Date']).sum()
        elif period == 'Week':
            self.data['Week'] = pd.to_datetime(self.data['Date']).dt.isocalendar().week
            return self.data.groupby('Week').sum()
        elif period == 'Month':
            self.data['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(self.data['Date']).dt.to_period('M')
            return self.data.groupby('Month').sum()
        else:
            print("Invalid period.")

em = ExpenseManager(data)

date_input = widgets.DatePicker(description='Date:')
category_input = widgets.Text(description='Category:')
amount_input = widgets.FloatText(description='Amount:')
add_button = widgets.Button(description='Add Expense')
remove_index_input = widgets.IntText(description='Index:')
remove_button = widgets.Button(description='Remove Expense')
display_button = widgets.Button(description='Display Data')

def add_expense(b):
    em.add_expense(date_input.value, category_input.value, amount_input.value)
    #print(f"Added expense: {date_input.value}, {category_input.value}, {amount_input.value}")
    with feedback_output:
        #feedback_output.clear_output() # from 'Output widgets: leveraging Jupyter’s display system' https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Output%20Widget.html
        print(f"Added expense: {date_input.value}, {category_input.value}, {amount_input.value}")
        #display(em.data)
        

def remove_expense(b):
    em.remove_expense(remove_index_input.value)
    #print(f"Removed expense at index: {remove_index_input.value}")
    with feedback_output:
        feedback_output.clear_output() # from 'Output widgets: leveraging Jupyter’s display system' https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Output%20Widget.html
        print(f"Removed expense at index: {remove_index_input.value}")
        #display(em.data)

def display_data(b):
    with feedback_output:
        feedback_output.clear_output() # from 'Output widgets: leveraging Jupyter’s display system' https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Output%20Widget.html
        display(em.data)

add_button.on_click(add_expense)
remove_button.on_click(remove_expense)
display_button.on_click(display_data)

display(date_input, category_input, amount_input, add_button, remove_index_input, remove_button, display_button)

period_input = widgets.Dropdown(options=['Day', 'Week', 'Month'], description='Period:')
analyze_button = widgets.Button(description='Analyze Expenses')

def analyze_expenses(b):
    period = period_input.value
    analysis = em.analyze_expenses(period)
    with feedback_output:
        feedback_output.clear_output() # from 'Output widgets: leveraging Jupyter’s display system' https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Output%20Widget.html
        display(analysis)
        analysis.plot(kind='bar')
        plt.show()

analyze_button.on_click(analyze_expenses)

display(period_input, analyze_button)

def generate_pdf_report(data, filename='expense_report.pdf'):
    c = canvas.Canvas(filename, pagesize=letter)
    width, height = letter
    c.drawString(30, height - 40, "Expense Report")
    
    y = height - 80
    for i, row in data.iterrows():
        c.drawString(30, y, f"{row['Date']} - {row['Category']} - ${row['Amount']}")
        y -= 20
        if y < 40:
            c.showPage()
            y = height - 40
    
    c.save()

pdf_button = widgets.Button(description='Generate PDF Report')

def create_pdf_report(b):
    generate_pdf_report(em.data)
    with feedback_output:
        feedback_output.clear_output() # from 'Output widgets: leveraging Jupyter’s display system' https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Output%20Widget.html
        print("PDF report generated.")

pdf_button.on_click(create_pdf_report)

display(pdf_button)

I didn't know how you wanted to handle things between the equivalent of each of your print() status updates. Right now, I clear out the previous ones with each new step. However, if you want something more akin to a rolling update in the cell like 'a paper trail' during the process, then comment out the feedback_output.clear_output() lines. The widgets will keep shifting to the bottom as the list of steps grow. I initially was testing things with having the add and remove steps show the updated dataframe as part of that step. I left it the code as commented out #display(em.data) though for now.
You'll need to actually use the 'Add Expense' button first, maybe twice, before trying the analyze buttons because otherwise my mock data won't have the columns needed.
More details:
Concerning code that will work with both flavors of current Jupyter (Jupyter Notbeook 7+ and JupyterLab) and handles print or the equivalent of print in ways compatible with current ipywidgets, see here and my comments here for more details with simpler examples. There's links there in to the pertinent ipywidgets documentation.

The answer is: wrong IDE
Yes, the problem was in my IDE, PyCharm. I switched to VSCode with the Jupyter Notebook extension and it worked!

That is not really fully the best answer. More of stop-gap or workaround, I suspect. You must be using old software with VSCode and Jupyter extension? Or something in there is still based on old things as print() won't work with modern Jupyter. When you update things it will break down the line. My approach to update the code is what you want for it to work in the long run as Jupyter and ipywidgets develop. Oh wait! Maybe you just mean the buttons work? And you don't care about the print() stuff. That I could see maybe being the case as those did work. Plus you focused on Jupyter only.

No. That was the key. I am using the newest version of PyCharm professional. I tried to launch this project but using the VSCode with the Jupyter Notebook extension. And it worked. That's really all. And it works completely fine.

The print() statements work, too? They shouldn't in current Jupyter and ipywidgets. I provided a lot showing you that is the case in the comments.

Yes, they works good. Everything works good. Thank you for your help.

Okay, if they are working with your original code, then either it is old stuff involved or VSCode added something to try and not leave them hanging out there. Either way it won't work in actual current Jupyter and so just be aware that you may be doing yourself a disservice in the long run by not adapting to what is needed to make it work in vanilla Jupyter. It won't be portable and if what you are using starts enforcing the current standards on handling, it will break.
